# Python socket noThreaded behaviour

Tags: python, sockets

If I have a pseudo code like this:

```
doSomeWork(_data):
    blah blah

if main:
    data=receiveDatafromSocket()
    doSomeWork(data)
```

My simple question is, if during doSomeWork() data arrives at the socket, I will wait until doSomeWork() finish before passing new data to that function?. The data remains in the buffer and then the code execute in an linear fashion, one after one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, assuming this is a TCP socket, incoming data is buffered by the system until you read it and maintains its order. If the system buffer fills, receives from the remote side are blocked until you read and make more room.